# How to remove Steps in Slider SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, uislider

I created a UISlider via SwiftUI, but there are just too many "step marks" along the track, which doesn't have the "look and feel" I wish to achieve. Anyone knows the trick to remove them other than turning the tint color to black?

It seems that the step/tick marks are always there as long as I pass any step values during UISlider initialization.

[image]

```
struct setLoggingView: View {
    
    @State var restfullness: Int
    @State var elapsedRestTime: Double
    var totalRestTime: Double
    var stepValue: Int

    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            ScrollView {
                
                VStack {
                    
                    Text("Rested  \(Int(elapsedRestTime)) seconds")
                    
                    Slider(value: $elapsedRestTime,
                           in: 0...totalRestTime,
                           step: Double.Stride(stepValue),
                           label: {
                        Text("Slider")
                    }, minimumValueLabel: {
                        Text("-\(stepValue)")
                    }, maximumValueLabel: {
                        Text("+\(stepValue)")
                    })
                        .tint(Color.white)
                        .padding(.bottom)

                    Divider()

                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("Restfullness")
                        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    
                    restfullnessStepper(restfullnessIndex: restfullness)
                
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Update Button Pressed")
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Update")
                                .fontWeight(.medium)
                        }
                    }
                    .cornerRadius(40)
                    
                }
                .border(Color.yellow)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, besides passing a different step value? Or passing nil to get rid of the tick marks altogether? I have steppable sliders in my iOS/macOS app; they work more-or-less sensibly according to the step value I pass in. Not sure about watchOS

Comment: I think it should be the same behavior in iOS and WatchOS if they use same SwiftUI. Yes, I mean, besides passing different step values to reduce the number of steps, I want to remove the tick marks, while maintaining the step values, because I want to show min/max labels.

Comment: 100% agree it **should be** the same. But this is Apple we're talking about. The sliders in iOS actually behave differently from the same sliders in macOS. That's why I said "more-or-less". Sorry not to be more help

Comment: I am posting this issue because if I remove the min/max labels, I will see plus and minus buttons on the sides, and it's a default behavior within Slider, so it makes it difficult for me to customize by adding buttons on the sides to the slider.

Comment: Thanks for your response and support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried research and asked a few mentors, but there seems to be no way to remove the steppers if you are using the default UISlider in SwiftUI. The only way is to create completely custom Slider, but I think I will just live with the default version.

Answer (score 1):

Until Apple improves SwiftUI, the way to do this is by providing a custom binding *INSTEAD OF* using the `step` parameter:

```
Slider(value: Binding(get: { dailyGoalMinutes }, 
                      set: { newValue in
                                let base: Int = Int(newValue.rounded())
                                let modulo: Int = base % 10     // Your step amount. Here, 10.
                                dailyGoalMinutes = Double(base - modulo)
                            }), 
                      in: 0...1440)
```

In this example, `dailyGoalMinutes` is declared on the view like this:

```
@State private var dailyGoalMinutes: Double = 180.0
```

The slider allows the user to select between 0 and 1,440 minutes (1 day) in 10-minute increments. While the slider itself won't snap to those increments while dragging, the value of `dailyGoalMinutes` will be properly constrained to multiples of 10 within the defined range.

(Note: AppKit behaves the same way; when `NSSlider` does not have any tick marks visible, the slider does not snap to values.)

Comment: My God Bryan thanks for answering this question. I have yet to try out your solution though, but I definitely will. Now working on some content marketing and holding off from my coding. But I will get back some day.